# JFrame is always on top

Tags: java, windows, swing, jframe

I'm doing a program in Java and I using `JPanel` for `the` interface, but I have a problem is always on top, I don't want this.  I want that when I restore another window this will be on the top.

I tried with:

```
this.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
```

But it is not working, the frame continues always on top.

Here is a simple program with my problem:

```
import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class BorrarRegistro extends JPanel
{

     public BorrarRegistro () {
     super(new BorderLayout());

     JLabel insertar= new JLabel("Registro");
     JTextField borrar= new JTextField();
     JButton borrar1= new JButton("Borrar Registro");

     JPanel borrarRegistro= new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,1));
     borrarRegistro.add(insertar);
     borrarRegistro.add(borrar);
     borrarRegistro.add(borrar1); 

     JPanel images= new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,3));


     add(images,BorderLayout.NORTH);
     add(borrarRegistro, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

  }

  private static void createAndShowGUI() {

    //Create and set up the window.
     JFrame frame = new JFrame("ClaseBase ");
     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

   // Create and set up the content pane.
     BorrarRegistro newContentPane = new BorrarRegistro ();
    newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
     frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

   // Display the window.
    frame.pack();
     frame.setVisible(true);

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
   // creating and showing this application's GUI.
     javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
           new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                 createAndShowGUI(); 
              }

           });
  }
}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: This is likely an OS issue.

Comment: Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!

Answer (score 3):

You should call `setAlwaysOnTop(false)` when you create the frame.

```
private static void createAndShowGUI() {

    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("ClaseBase ");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    // Create and set up the content pane.
    Test newContentPane = new Test();
    newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //con
    frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);// tent panes must be opaque
    frame.setAlwaysOnTop(false);

    // Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```